# Sales orders is not displayed in admin panel in grid of Magento2.2.0?

Tags: sales-order, magento2.2

[image]After data migration process I see that orders data is not displayed in Magento admin sales grid.

All data is available in the database. Than why data is not in sales grid?

**Anyone has idea about this problem?**

Comment: Do reindex and test

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Disable `Asynchronous indexing` under `Store > Configuration > Advance > Developer > Grid Settings`

[image]

Clear cache (optional reindexing) or set up a cron job.

Comment: hello, @Adnan, Already asynchronous indexing is disabled in my case, but still grid is not showing for me

Comment: @jafarpinjar what is your magento version?

Comment: additionally, please, if you have upgraded from previous version of Magento then completely clear the cache and run the reindex, double check that Async Indexing is disabled from config.

Comment: @Adnan i am getting the error "Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state." can u please advise

Comment: @NagarajuKasa where you are facing the error, on sales order grid? If you have made any change to sales order grid (e.g. third-party extension or customization) please remove them, flush the cache, clear generated/code directory if the error resolves then put back your customization one by one and see when the error triggers again, it will help you to debug the issue.

Comment: Fixed it for me. Cleaned cache. Didn't need to reindex. Why in the world does enabling this cause the problem?! Is it a bug? Most places recommend leaving this enabled for improved performance.

Comment: @Rooster242 you are right, leaving this enabled has a significant effect on performance but it requires further configuration and environment modifications. Remember it doesn't implement on all versions of Magento.

Answer (score 2):

**Disable Async Grid Indexing**

As mentioned in the other answer, you can disable it by going to

> Store > Configuration > Advance > Developer > Grid Settings > Asynchronous indexing

You can do the same from the command line:

View the settings value: `bin/magento config:show dev/grid/async_indexing`

Enable: `bin/magento config:set dev/grid/async_indexing 1`

Disable: `bin/magento config:set dev/grid/async_indexing 0`

**Run Cron Job**

It is not recommended to disable async grid indexing as it might degrade the performance.

The grid updates are done by the scheduled cron job.

The best solution would be to run the cron job at regular intervals.

Or, you can also run cron job manually via the following command:

> bin/magento cron:run

After that, refresh cache: `bin/magento cache:flush`

Ref: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales/order-grid-updates-schedule.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this tool
https://github.com/trunglv/mage2_dev

Example:

### Build for all missing orders

```
sudo bin/magento beta_dev:build_order_grid --missing-orders true
```

### Build for a specific order -- In case you want to refresh just one item due to just missing a few fields.

```
sudo bin/magento beta_dev:build_order_grid --missing-orders [order_id]
```